# Excel -- Comparing dates in different formats

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying to run a formula that essentially compares two different date columns to determine if another formula needs to be run but I'm running into trouble because the dates are in different formats. For example, I have column A with dates in DD-MMM-YY format and column B where the dates are in QYY format.

DATE    INCOME_QTR  STATUS

22-Feb-05   1Q18
13-Oct-17   1Q18
29-Apr-08   1Q18
03-Oct-16   1Q18
05-Apr-19   1Q18
02-Mar-15   1Q18

Essentially I want to do an IF statement to determine if the date in column A is greater than or equal to the quarter to determine if the data tied to the first date should be incorporated into the Quarter shown in column B. In simpler terms, only row 6 would be "yes" in this case because the date in column A is greater than the Quarter in column B.

I've been trying to run =IF(TEXT([@[date]],"YYYYMMDD">TEXT([@[income_qtr]],"YYYYMMDD")),"YES","No") but I haven't been successful.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this without adding any modules or using VBA.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> =IF(RIGHT(A1,2)>RIGHT(B1,2),"Yes",IF(RIGHT(A1,2)<RIGHT(B1,2),"No",IF(IF(OR(MID(A1,4,3)="Jan",MID(A1,4,3)="Feb",MID(A1,4,3)="Mar"),1,IF(OR(MID(A1,4,3)="Apr",MID(A1,4,3)="May",MID(A1,4,3)="Jun"),2,IF(OR(MID(A1,4,3)="Jul",MID(A1,4,3)="Aug",MID(A1,4,3)="Sep"),3,4)))>=RIGHT(B1,1),"Yes","No")))

That's the formula for A1 and B1...